# send alert mail when file not found at specific time using java

Tags: java

I am trying to sent an alert mail to users if the file is not present or modified at a location after a specified time.
For ex.
I am looking for a file MASTER.csv at C:\Users\Desktop location.
If this file is not changed or not present at above location after 4:00 AM PARIS TIME since last day then it will send an alert mail to users informing them we have not received the file at agreed SLA.

For mail send i have written the class just not able to figure out how trigger that class at specified time if the file is not present or changed.

i have written an watcher class which check when the file is present at above location then it will call other class but not the other way around.

```
public class FileWatchDemo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                // Creates a instance of WatchService.
                WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

                // Registers the logDir below with a watch service.
                Path logDir = Paths.get("C:\\\\Users\\\\Desktop\\\\");
                logDir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_MODIFY, ENTRY_DELETE);

                // Monitor the logDir at listen for change notification.
                WatchKey watchKey = null;
                while (true) {
                    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();                           

                    WatchKey key = watcher.take();
                    for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {                          

                        WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

                        if (ENTRY_CREATE.equals(kind)) {
                            System.out.println("Entry was created on log dir.");
                        } else if (ENTRY_MODIFY.equals(kind)) {
                            System.out.println("Entry was modified on log dir.");
                        } else if (ENTRY_DELETE.equals(kind)) {
                            System.out.println("Entry was deleted from log dir.");
                        }
                    }
                    key.reset();
                }
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


}
```

This code does not move ahead after the code

```
WatchKey key = watcher.take();
```

if it did not detect any file change in the location thats where i stuck how to check at 4:00 AM is the file is present or not.

Comment: If you only need to check the file at 4:00 AM then schedule your program to run at that time only. I mean write a program that executes your logic at 4:00 AM using Spring Scheduler(or any other framework).

Comment: i am not very much familiar with spring scheduler will check if this fits in my overall requirement

Comment: Watch Service API should be used when you want to be notified about file change events. In your case, you should schedule your program to run at 4:00 AM and execute your business logic. Also, I quickly ran your program and it's working fine. Check if the file path is correct. Are you modifying your file at that location to test the program?

Comment: Yes this code running fine but for another purpose.
i need a same one which will send alert after 4:00 Am if is not received or changed at this path.
I know what to do but how to do is question

Comment: ok. This line is confusing --> "This code does not move ahead after the code". Anyways, I hope you have got pointers for implementing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If your main problem is to schedule a process, there are some ways you can do it

- Relying on your operating system (Windows = Task Scheduduler / Linux = Crontab), create a task there for every day at 4 to execute your program.
- Create a code with `java.util.TimerTask` or `ScheduledExecutorService` or `java.util.Timer`, for every X hours to call a method
- Use a framework like `Quartz`, `Guava AbstractScheduledService` or Spring Scheduling

With this you don't need a service to 'watch' the file, you just need to check if it exists `(new File("C:\\a\\b\\c")).exists()` or the last time it was modified (`new Date((new File("C:\\a\\b\\c")).lastModified())`)

Examples (note that the codes below are just simple examples for test/learning, they should be improved, or APIs should be used):

**Simple thread**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        // do something every 10 seconds
                        doSomething();
                        Thread.sleep(10000); 
                    } 
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private static void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("working");
    }
```

**With TimerTask and Timer**

```
public class Main extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doSomething();
    }

    private static void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("working");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimerTask timerTask = new Main();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);
    }

}
```

**With ScheduledExecutorService**

```
private static void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("working");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                doSomething();
            }
        };

        ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 5, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

Comment: I am using Windows machine so CRONTAB will not an option for me and i dont think they will let me use use the task schedule as well.
i will check the API's metioned by you in second option however i am a newbie on JAVA

Comment: For using option 2 (pure java) or option 3 (external frameworks) you don't need the watch service, just create a method to check if the file exits, create a scheduler with the api you decide, configure it to run every X hours or at a specific time, and from this scheduler call your 'check file' method. After this export you program as runnable jar and execute it. This runnable jar needs to be active 24h. There are other fancier ways to do it, but this should cover your needs and is simple enough.

Comment: Thanks for Reply - I need pure JAVA solution as it has to be integrated with a larger solution which all written in JAVA.
I am now trying learn  import java.util.TimerTask API .
If i am not asking much could you please provide me any example where scheduler method is being used to call method such as check file in every 10 minutes or whatever time interval and then call another method at 4:00 AM or any other time 
just asking cause new to JAVA you may ignore the request if not suited :)

Comment: i found an example on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-timertask-class-java/
trying to digest it